# php session not starting

Tags: php, session

Hi guys I'm trying to start new session in PHP CMS Application
but when i tried to start session with username and password to access main.php page it is redirecting to login page and showing no error

This is my login.php script:

```
<?php
session_start();

require('../config/connect.php');
if (isset($_POST['userid']) and isset($_POST['password'])){
$username = $_POST['userid'];
$password = md5($_POST['password']);
$query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);
$row=  mysql_fetch_array($result);
$userid = $row['userid'];
$usertype= $row['usertype'];
if ($count == 1){
$_SESSION['userid'] = $userid;
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
$_SESSION['usertype'] = $usertype;

   if($_SESSION['usertype'] == 'ADMIN'){
    // echo "ADMIN AREA";
   header("Location:../admin/index.php");
   }elseif ($_SESSION['usertype'] == 'STUDENT'){
    //echo "STUDENT AREA";

    header("Location:../students/index.php");
   }else{
    echo "CLINT AREA";
   }

}else{
echo "<script>
alert(' Invalid Username And Password');
window.location.href='../index.php';
</script>";

 }
}


?>
```

and this is my session start code

```
<?php
session_start();



if(isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])){      



echo 'Start Session now';



}
else

{
header("Location:../index.php");

}

?>
```

Comment: One does not simply use md5 for hashing passwords in database calls vulnerable to sql injection

Comment: And where are you declaring `logged_in` index? Did you mean `userid` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you already put `userid` $_SESSION['userid'] = $userid; in session .you didn't put `logged_in` in session .

so use `userid` instead `logged_in`

```
<?php
session_start();
if(empty($_SESSION['userid']))
{
header("location:login.php");
}
else

{
header("Location:../index.php");

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not use **logged_in** index in your code.

So, you should change your code like @Mr7-itsurdeveloper provided answer.

OR

```
 <?php
session_start();
if(!empty($_SESSION['userid']) && !empty($_SESSION(username)))
{
  header("Location:../index.php");
}
else

{
  header("location:login.php");
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure session_start(); is called before any sessions are being called. So a safe bet would be to put it at the beginning of your page, immediately after the opening

After the header redirect, end the current script using exit(); (Others have also suggested session_write_close(); and session_regenerate_id(true), you can try those as well, but I'd use exit();)

Make sure cookies are enabled in the browser you are using to test it on.